# Warning Code : 1264 Out of range value for column for datetime column value

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

Here's my query:

```
UPDATE lynn_mis_goodsales SET accepteddate = '2011-02-30 13:24:50' WHERE created LIKE '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

The column value is datetime, and the error given is:

```
Warning Code : 1264
Out of range value for column 'accepteddate'
```

What can be the reason for this error when I use SQLYog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it looks like your date is February 30, which will cause an error since that date does not exist anywhere I'm aware of :)

Comment: Oh my soul!! How could I have missed that!! You are correct and the issue is resolved!!

Comment: @learner23 Ha, good to hear! September 31 is the one that always gets me :)

Comment: LOL! maybe this will help someone else that also misses this!! THANX ALOT!!

Comment: @learner23 Haha, hopefully! No problem at all, glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: @JohnWoo Haha, I think one of my life goals was to get a +1 from you. I guess now I can retire :)